# access to different levels of a json file

Tags: objective-c, json

how do I access the contents of group?

Currently, I can access bookmarks and blog.

I think the two characters after group generate problem of reading.

Here's code that selects the data from the json file to display data

```
 NSDictionary *feed = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"object"];
 NSArray *entries = [feed objectForKey:@"bookmarks"];

for (NSDictionary *item in entries)

{
 [item objectForKey:@"SomeDataIdentifierOfBookmarks"]
}
```

Here is the JSON file read by a NSMutableArray

EDIT REAL DATA JSON

{"object":
    {"blog":[{"guid":181,"type":"object","subtype":"4","time_created":"","time_updated":"","container_guid":"180","owner_guid":"180","site_guid":"1","title":"ugyt","description":"scsa","url":"http://s210678217.onlinehome.fr/blog/view/181/ugg-sito-ufficiale-italiavyt"}],
    "bookmarks":[{"guid":82,"type":"object","subtype":"9","time_created":"1372072736","time_updated":"1372072910","container_guid":"81","owner_guid":"33","site_guid":"1","title":"internet - ","description":"","url":"hr"},
    {"guid":75,"type":"object","subtype":"9","time_created":"1371728924","time_updated":"1371728924","container_guid":"64","owner_guid":"52","site_guid":"1","title":" du ","description":"

p>","url":"htts"},
    {"guid":64,"type":"group","subtype":"0","time_created":"1371728148","time_updated":"1372068044","container_guid":"33","owner_guid":"33","site_guid":"1","name":"  yvelines","description":"

Le.</p>","url":"http://ses"}
         ]
     ]
}

Thanks

Comment: Your square brackets don't match up. You've got 4 open brackets and 1 close bracket. This means that for every open bracket, it should have an accompanying close bracket.

Answer (score 1):

This is not close to being valid JSON.  Use http://jsonlint.com to make sure you have valid inputs before worrying about your code for unpacking the data. You have multiple un-closed arrays (the "[" character starts an array, "]" ends it, and at least one missing comma (before "bookmarks").  It's hard to tell what is wrong with this JSON, because there are enough errors that the intent is not clear.

Your code for accessing the contents is mostly fine, except that "SomeDataIdentifierOfBookmarks" isn't a key that is in your JSON—I presume you mean that would be replaced with an actual value.

*Edit:* Your pasted actual JSON is trying to close the "object" object with a square bracket rather than a curly bracket.  jsonlint will turn those errors up quickly.

Comment: This is not my real JSON file, but a simple outline.
How to reach my true json file to forum post?

Comment: Post Update with json data file